# rxjs transformation methods on observable run synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Do rxjs transformation methods on observable run synchronous or asynchronous?

e.g. in angular 2 http GET req and map response to JSON object:

```
this.http.get('some/url').map(res => res.json());
```

What if I have to parse 2MiB JSON and store it (e.g. Pouchdb). Do these operations run in background non blocking way or not? If not how can I achieve async behaviour for these ops.

Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded and asynchronous as long as your code is asynchronous. This means that if your code is blocking (long running loop) then you're blocking other code to be executed.

RxJS doesn't use WebWorkers so everything you do is blocking the execution thread.

I think if you want to process data in a non blocking way there's currently no other way than implementing it by yourself with WebWorkers.

Also, note that asynchronous doesn't mean parallel.

Comment: please take a look at my following question, what lib would you suggest using for background work in angular2/typescript ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488724/angular2-work-in-background-thread-with-custom-serializable-objects